# How to use select() on sockets properly?

Tags: c, sockets, select

I'm trying to wrap my head around calling `select` on sockets and I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

`setup_server_socket` calls `bind` and `listen` and sets the socket to nonblocking mode.

The following code blocks on the `select` call it seems, not moving forward to `FD_ISSET`. I tried connecting a client and it seems to succeed but `select` never returns anything.

What's the proper way to do this?

```
...
int listenfd = setup_server_socket( serverPort );

if( -1 == listenfd )
    return 1;

fd_set read_fds;
FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
int fdmax = listenfd;


// loop forever
while( 1 )
{
    if (select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, NULL,NULL,NULL) == -1){
        perror("select");
        exit(4);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<= fdmax; i++){
        printf("Testing: %d, %d\n", i, FD_ISSET(i,&read_fds));

    }return 0;
...
```

Comment: From the fine manual: `... If  time‐
       out is NULL (no timeout), select() can block indefinitely. ...` BTW: a -1 return from select() is *not an error*

Comment: Sure but just because it CAN doesn't mean it should... the problem I was having was that FD_ISSET never returned anything, despite clients being connected. But it was because I didn't use FD_SET first.

Comment: Also: you have to reinitialize read_fds *every time* before calling select() (select alters the fd_sets ) . Mostly this is done by copying from yet another fd_set.

Comment: Sweet, I think I'm starting to get it now.

Comment: And, after a -1 return from select, *thou should check errno* , especially EINTR/EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK should not be treated as error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Read several times [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html), [select_tut(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select_tut.2.html), [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) (BTW, you should prefer [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) to the obsolete `select`, which don't handle file descriptors bigger than `__FD_SETSIZE`, i.e. 1024 on my Linux/Debian/x86-64 system).

Then:

```
fd_set read_fds;
FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
int fdmax = listenfd;
FD_SET(listenfd, &read_fds);
```

should go *inside* the `while(1)`  loop, before calling `select`. BTW, I recommend using `poll` instead of `select`

Read also about the [C10k problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem)

Don't forget that `select` is changing its given `fd_set`-s (and usually wants them to be non-empty)...

Perhaps use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html). If you compile with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), invoke it as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` to get more warnings and debug info. If you compile your C code with [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/), consider using the [Clang Static Analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/).

Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) (it is a free book that you could also read on paper, or download from several other places, e.g. [this](http://richard.esplins.org/static/downloads/linux_book.pdf) etc...)

Comment: Sorry, do you mean I should just refer to the man pages? I've done that to the best of my ability :(

Comment: I mean I'm convinced those are nice links but I'm trying to walk before I run here... Also, broken link on Advanced Linux Programming

Comment: It used to be a working link, and it is a book that  you might read on paper.

Answer (score 2):

here is one (trimmed) example of using select()

```
INT32    selectStatus;                                 /* select() return code */

char     tempreport[ 256 ] = {'\0'};

struct   timeval tv;

fd_set   fdread;
//fd_set   fdwrite;
//fd_set   fdexcep;



// note:
//  must try to read report until no report available 
// so have latest report in buffer
do
{
    /* Note: timeout must be (re)set every time before call to select() */
    tv.tv_sec = 1;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;


    FD_ZERO(&fdread);
    FD_SET( FD, &fdread );

    selectStatus = select(FD+1, &fdread, NULL, NULL, &tv);

    switch( selectStatus )
    {
        case -1:
            ....
            break;

        case 0:
            // timeout, I.E. nothing to read
            ....
            break;

        default: /* available to read */

            memset(tempreport, 0x00, sizeof(tempreport) );
            readStatus = read_UDP_socket( FD, tempreport, sizeof(tempreport), &readCount );

            break;
    } // end switch( selectStatus )
} while( (0 < selectStatus)&&(eRS_Success == readStatus ) );
 // exit loop on select timeout or select error or read failure
```

notes:

```
eRS_Success is an entry from an enum used for various return codes
read_UDP_socket() is a local function
```